Pyspark convert array string to array while loading to file
I have a dataframe, the truncated version of which looks like below
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|     input_file_name|              ROW_ID|  FAILED_VALIDATIONS|VALIDATION_STATUS|  MEMBER_ID|      RECORDS_HEADER|         RECORDS_001|         RECORDS_002|         RECORDS_003|         RECORDS_004|         RECORDS_005|         RECORDS_006|         RECORDS_007|            batch_id|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|s3://gov-solution...|a64fbbea-7cf3-43e...|                null|           PASSED|U7742139901|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"BATCH_BEGIN_DA...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|d0f87fd5-fca1-4e2...|
|s3://gov-solution...|a64fbbea-7cf3-43e...|MEMBER_ID is missing|           FAILED|           |[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"BATCH_BEGIN_DA...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|d0f87fd5-fca1-4e2...|
|s3://gov-solution...|a64fbbea-7cf3-43e...|MEMBER_ID is miss...|           FAILED|           |[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"BATCH_BEGIN_DA...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|d0f87fd5-fca1-4e2...|
|s3://gov-solution...|a64fbbea-7cf3-43e...|                null|           PASSED|U6881487301|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"BATCH_BEGIN_DA...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|[{"RECORD_TYPE":"...|                null|d0f87fd5-fca1-4e2...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+

When I load each record to S3 file using foreach(), then it loads into below format -
{
    "input_file_name": "s3://gov-solutions-dev-fulfillment2-files/Input-Data/EOBLetter/20240327/MONTHLY_EOB_U6881487301_20231218180516.json",
    "ROW_ID": "1f6df8f3-7cb7-4a29-999c-ea8f5923168a",
    "FAILED_VALIDATIONS": null,
    "VALIDATION_STATUS": "PASSED",
    "MEMBER_ID": "U6881487301",
    "RECORDS_HEADER": "[{\"RECORD_TYPE\":\"HEADER\",\"COUNT_OF_OBJECTS_RECORD_TYPE_001\":1,\"COUNT_OF_OBJECTS_RECORD_TYPE_002\":3,\"COUNT_OF_OBJECTS_RECORD_TYPE_003\":6,\"COUNT_OF_OBJECTS_RECORD_TYPE_004\":3,\"COUNT_OF_OBJECTS_RECORD_TYPE_005\":1,\"COUNT_OF_OBJECTS_RECORD_TYPE_006\":1,\"COUNT_OF_OBJECTS_RECORD_TYPE_007\":0}]",
    "RECORDS_001": "[{\"BATCH_BEGIN_DATE\":\"01/01/2023\",\"BATCH_END_DATE\":\"11/30/2023\",\"BATCH_ID\":1000000078,\"BATCH_RUN_DATE\":\"12/18/2023\",\"BATCH_STATUS\":\"COMPLETE\",\"COLATERAL_TYPE\":\"EOB\",\"INDIV_ID\":\"3003790\",\"MBR_PREF_LANG\":\"English\",\"MBR_PREF_LARGE_PRINT\":\"N\",\"MEMBER_ID\":\"U6881487301\",\"SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID\":\"GBSF\"}]",
    "RECORDS_002": "[{\"RECORD_TYPE\":\"002\",\"CLAIM_DOS_BEGIN_DT\":\"08/29/2023\",\"CLAIM_DOS_END_DT\":\"08/29/2023\",\"CLAIM_NUMBER\":\"23E002113200\",\"CLAIM_QMB_ELIG\":\"Y\",\"CLAIM_TYP\":\"H\",\"CLASS_ID\":\"\",\"CLASS_PLAN_ID\":\"\",\"CONTRACT_ID\":\"H0354\",\"GROUP_ID\":\"\",\"PAID_DATE\":\"09/15/2023\",\"PAR_IND\":\"N\",\"PBP\":\"027\",\"PROCESSED_DATE\":\"09/16/2023\",\"RECEIVED_DATE\":\"08/30/2023\",\"RENDERING_PROVIDER_NAME\":\"ESCHLER, DAVID J\",\"SEGMENT\":\"000\",\"PAR_IND_1\":\"Out-Of-Network\",\"CLAIM_QMB_ELIG_1\":\"Y\",\"ClaimLines_ServiceDataRange\":\"08/29/2023 - 08/29/2023\"},{\"RECORD_TYPE\":\"002\",\"CLAIM_DOS_BEGIN_DT\":\"05/25/2023\",\"CLAIM_DOS_END_DT\":\"05/25/2023\",\"CLAIM_NUMBER\":\"23P001125500\",\"CLAIM_QMB_ELIG\":\"N\",\"CLAIM_TYP\":\"H\",\"CLASS_ID\":\"\",\"CLASS_PLAN_ID\":\"\",\"CONTRACT_ID\":\"H0354\",\"GROUP_ID\":\"\",\"PAID_DATE\":\"06/15/2023\",\"PAR_IND\":\"Y\",\"PBP\":\"001\",\"PROCESSED_DATE\":\"06/16/2023\",\"RECEIVED_DATE\":\"05/30/2023\",\"RENDERING_PROVIDER_NAME\":\"PRAC HH, MHK HOME G.\",\"SEGMENT\":\"000\",\"PAR_IND_1\":\"In-Network\",\"CLAIM_QMB_ELIG_1\":\"\",\"ClaimLines_ServiceDataRange\":\"05/25/2023 - 05/25/2023\"},{\"RECORD_TYPE\":\"002\",\"CLAIM_DOS_BEGIN_DT\":\"01/12/2024\",\"CLAIM_DOS_END_DT\":\"01/12/2024\",\"CLAIM_NUMBER\":\"23E002114300\",\"CLAIM_QMB_ELIG\":\"N\",\"CLAIM_TYP\":\"H\",\"CLASS_ID\":\"\",\"CLASS_PLAN_ID\":\"\",\"CONTRACT_ID\":\"H0354\",\"GROUP_ID\":\"\",\"PAID_DATE\":\"01/15/2024\",\"PAR_IND\":\"Y\",\"PBP\":\"028\",\"PROCESSED_DATE\":\"01/16/2024\",\"RECEIVED_DATE\":\"01/30/2024\",\"RENDERING_PROVIDER_NAME\":\"ZEN, MAX\",\"SEGMENT\":\"000\",\"PAR_IND_1\":\"In-Network\",\"CLAIM_QMB_ELIG_1\":\"\",\"ClaimLines_ServiceDataRange\":\"01/12/2024 - 01/12/2024\"}]",
    "RECORDS_003": "[{\"RECORD_TYPE\":\"003\",\"ALLOWED\":\"0.00\",\"BILLING_CODE\":\"96401\",\"BILLING_CODE_DESC\":\"Complex medication injected\",\"CLAIMLN_DOS_BEGIN_DT\":\"08/29/2023\",\"CLAIMLN_DOS_END_DT\":\"08/29/2023\",\"CLAIM_LINE_NUMBER\":\"2\",\"CLAIM_NUMBER\":\"23E002113200\",\"CLAIM_STATUS_DENIED\":\"Y\",\"COINSURANCE\":\"$10.00\",\"COINSURANCE_PCT\":\"0.00\",\"COPAY\":\"Y\",\"DEDUCTIBLE\":\"$910.00\",\"LINE_NOTES_CODE\":\"B\",\"OVERAGE_AMOUNT\":\"$0.00\",\"PAID_AMT\":\"0.00\",\"PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY\":\"$0.00\",\"TOTAL_CHARGE\":\"$475.00\",\"DEDUCTIBLE_STATEMENT\":\"Y\",\"COINSURANCE_STATEMENT\":\"Y\",\"OVERAGE_STATEMENT\":\"N\"},{\"RECORD_TYPE\":\"003\",\"ALLOWED\":\"0.00\",\"BILLING_CODE\":\"96401\",\"BILLING_CODE_DESC\":\"Complex medication injected\",\"CLAIMLN_DOS_BEGIN_DT\":\"08/29/2023\",\"CLAIMLN_DOS_END_DT\":\"08/29/2023\",\"CLAIM_LINE_NUMBER\":\"4\",\"CLAIM_NUMBER\":\"23E002113200\",\"CLAIM_STATUS_DENIED\":\"Y\",\"COINSURANCE\":\"$0.00\",\"COINSURANCE_PCT\":\"0.00\",\"COPAY\":\"N\",\"DEDUCTIBLE\":\"$0.00\",\"LINE_NOTES_CODE\":\"B\",\"OVERAGE_AMOUNT\":\"$0.00\",\"PAID_AMT\":\"0.00\",\"PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY\":\"$0.00\",\"TOTAL_CHARGE\":\"$475.00\",\"DEDUCTIBLE_STATEMENT\":\"N\",\"COINSURANCE_STATEMENT\":\"N\",\"OVERAGE_STATEMENT\":\"N\"},{\"RECORD_TYPE\":\"003\",\"ALLOWED\":\"900.00\",\"BILLING_CODE\":\"A0428\",\"BILLING_CODE_DESC\":\"Ambulance transport\",\"CLAIMLN_DOS_BEGIN_DT\":\"01/12/2024\",\"CLAIMLN_DOS_END_DT\":\"01/12/2024\",\"CLAIM_LINE_NUMBER\":\"1\",\"CLAIM_NUMBER\":\"23E002114300\",\"CLAIM_STATUS_DENIED\":\"N\",\"COINSURANCE\":\"$0.00\",\"COINSURANCE_PCT\":\"0.00\",\"COPAY\":\"Y\",\"DEDUCTIBLE\":\"$0.00\",\"LINE_NOTES_CODE\":\"\",\"OVERAGE_AMOUNT\":\"$0.00\",\"PAID_AMT\":\"700.00\",\"PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY\":\"$200.00\",\"TOTAL_CHARGE\":\"$1800.00\",\"DEDUCTIBLE_STATEMENT\":\"N\",\"COINSURANCE_STATEMENT\":\"N\",\"OVERAGE_STATEMENT\":\"N\"},{\"RECORD_TYPE\":\"003\",\"ALLOWED\":\"0.00\",\"BILLING_CODE\":\"96401\",\"BILLING_CODE_DESC\":\"Complex medication injected\",\"CLAIMLN_DOS_BEGIN_DT\":\"08/29/2023\",\"CLAIMLN_DOS_END_DT\":\"08/29/2023\",\"CLAIM_LINE_NUMBER\":\"1\",\"CLAIM_NUMBER\":\"23E002113200\",\"CLAIM_STATUS_DENIED\":\"Y\",\"COINSURANCE\":\"$0.00\",\"COINSURANCE_PCT\":\"0.00\",\"COPAY\":\"N\",\"DEDUCTIBLE\":\"$0.00\",\"LINE_NOTES_CODE\":\"B\",\"OVERAGE_AMOUNT\":\"$0.00\",\"PAID_AMT\":\"0.00\",\"PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY\":\"$0.00\",\"TOTAL_CHARGE\":\"$475.00\",\"DEDUCTIBLE_STATEMENT\":\"N\",\"COINSURANCE_STATEMENT\":\"N\",\"OVERAGE_STATEMENT\":\"N\"},{\"RECORD_TYPE\":\"003\",\"ALLOWED\":\"0.00\",\"BILLING_CODE\":\"96401\",\"BILLING_CODE_DESC\":\"Complex medication injected\",\"CLAIMLN_DOS_BEGIN_DT\":\"08/29/2023\",\"CLAIMLN_DOS_END_DT\":\"08/29/2023\",\"CLAIM_LINE_NUMBER\":\"3\",\"CLAIM_NUMBER\":\"23E002113200\",\"CLAIM_STATUS_DENIED\":\"Y\",\"COINSURANCE\":\"$0.00\",\"COINSURANCE_PCT\":\"0.00\",\"COPAY\":\"N\",\"DEDUCTIBLE\":\"$0.00\",\"LINE_NOTES_CODE\":\"B\",\"OVERAGE_AMOUNT\":\"$40.00\",\"PAID_AMT\":\"0.00\",\"PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY\":\"$0.00\",\"TOTAL_CHARGE\":\"$475.00\",\"DEDUCTIBLE_STATEMENT\":\"N\",\"COINSURANCE_STATEMENT\":\"N\",\"OVERAGE_STATEMENT\":\"Y\"},{\"RECORD_TYPE\":\"003\",\"ALLOWED\":\"335.77\",\"BILLING_CODE\":\"G6015\",\"BILLING_CODE_DESC\":\"Radiation treatment (IMRT)\",\"CLAIMLN_DOS_BEGIN_DT\":\"05/25/2023\",\"CLAIMLN_DOS_END_DT\":\"05/25/2023\",\"CLAIM_LINE_NUMBER\":\"1\",\"CLAIM_NUMBER\":\"23P001125500\",\"CLAIM_STATUS_DENIED\":\"N\",\"COINSURANCE\":\"$67.15\",\"COINSURANCE_PCT\":\"20.00\",\"COPAY\":\"N\",\"DEDUCTIBLE\":\"$0.00\",\"LINE_NOTES_CODE\":\"\",\"OVERAGE_AMOUNT\":\"$0.00\",\"PAID_AMT\":\"268.62\",\"PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY\":\"$67.15\",\"TOTAL_CHARGE\":\"$1000.00\",\"DEDUCTIBLE_STATEMENT\":\"N\",\"COINSURANCE_STATEMENT\":\"Y\",\"OVERAGE_STATEMENT\":\"N\"}]",
    "RECORDS_004": "[{\"RECORD_TYPE\":\"004\",\"CLAIM_ALLOWED\":\"900.00\",\"CLAIM_COINSURANCE\":\"0.00\",\"CLAIM_COPAY\":\"200.00\",\"CLAIM_DEDUCTIBLE\":\"0.00\",\"CLAIM_NUMBER\":\"23E002114300\",\"CLAIM_OVERAGE_AMOUNT\":\"0.00\",\"CLAIM_PAID_AMT\":\"$700.00\",\"CLAIM_PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY\":\"200.00\",\"CLAIM_TOTAL_CHARGE\":\"1800.00\"},{\"RECORD_TYPE\":\"004\",\"CLAIM_ALLOWED\":\"335.77\",\"CLAIM_COINSURANCE\":\"67.15\",\"CLAIM_COPAY\":\"0.00\",\"CLAIM_DEDUCTIBLE\":\"0.00\",\"CLAIM_NUMBER\":\"23P001125500\",\"CLAIM_OVERAGE_AMOUNT\":\"0.00\",\"CLAIM_PAID_AMT\":\"$268.62\",\"CLAIM_PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY\":\"67.15\",\"CLAIM_TOTAL_CHARGE\":\"1000.00\"},{\"RECORD_TYPE\":\"004\",\"CLAIM_ALLOWED\":\"0.00\",\"CLAIM_COINSURANCE\":\"0.00\",\"CLAIM_COPAY\":\"0.00\",\"CLAIM_DEDUCTIBLE\":\"0.00\",\"CLAIM_NUMBER\":\"23E002113200\",\"CLAIM_OVERAGE_AMOUNT\":\"0.00\",\"CLAIM_PAID_AMT\":\"$0.00\",\"CLAIM_PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY\":\"0.00\",\"CLAIM_TOTAL_CHARGE\":\"1900.00\"}]",
    "RECORDS_005": "[{\"RECORD_TYPE\":\"005\",\"PROCESSED_PERIOD_ALLOWED_AMT\":\"1235.77\",\"PROCESSED_PERIOD_AMOUNT_CHARGED\":\"4700.00\",\"PROCESSED_PERIOD_PAID_AMT\":\"968.62\",\"PROCESSED_PERIOD_PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY\":\"267.15\"}]",
    "RECORDS_006": "[{\"RECORD_TYPE\":\"006\",\"CLAIM_NOTE_CODE\":\"B\",\"END_DATE\":\"11/30/2024\",\"MAX_SERVICE_CTG_DEDUCTIBLE\":\"$0.00\",\"MEM_PAID_DEDUCTIBLE\":\"$0.00\",\"MEM_PAID_MOOP_COMBINED\":\"0.00\",\"MEM_PAID_MOOP_INNETWRK\":\"267.15\",\"MOOP_MAX_COMBINED\":\"0.00\",\"MOOP_MAX_INNETWRK\":\"3100.00\",\"PAID_TOWARDS_SERVICE_CTG\":\"$0.00\",\"PLAN_COINSURANCE\":\"Y\",\"PLAN_COPAY\":\"Y\",\"PLAN_DEDUCTIBLE\":\"$0.00\",\"PLAN_YEAR\":\"2024\",\"PLAN_YEAR_BEGIN_DT\":\"01/01/2024\",\"PLAN_YEAR_END_DT\":\"12/31/2024\",\"SERVICE_CTG_IND\":\"N\",\"SERVICE_CTG_TYPE\":\"\",\"START_DATE\":\"01/01/2024\",\"YT_ALLOWED_AMOUNT\":\"1235.77\",\"YT_AMOUNT_CHARGED\":\"4700.00\",\"YT_MEMLIABILITY_AMT\":\"$267.15\",\"YT_PAID_AMT\":\"968.62\",\"PLAN_DEDUCTIBLE_BAR_GRAPH\":\"N\"}]",
    "RECORDS_007": null,
    "batch_id": "302bdcc8-dec1-445a-86a6-0409d3959b75"
}

What I want is while loading into a file the json string values should be converted to json for field starting with RECORDS_*
I have below function which I run using foreach() to load each row to S3 file -
def write_final_json(row):
    print("in write_final_json")
    if row.VALIDATION_STATUS == 'PASSED':
        # Initialize S3 client
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    
        # S3 bucket and directory
        bucket_name = 'gov-solutions-dev-fulfillment2-files'
        output_dir = 'Extracted-Data/EOBLetter/Ready'
        
        # Create JSON string from row
        json_data = json.dumps(row.asDict())
        
        # Define S3 key
        s3_key = f"{output_dir}/{row.batch_id}/{row.MEMBER_ID}.json"
    
        # Write JSON data to S3
        s3.put_object(Body=json_data, Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_key)

Please let me know where I can convert the json string to json so that I can see only json in the file

WHERE you do it is just after your if statement, before you convert to JSON.  You will need to decide what you want the nested structure to look like.  Do you want a list of subrecords?

Thanks @Tim for replying. I just want the format to be exactly same what I am getting, but just without double quotes, basically the "[{"RECORD_TYPE":"HEADER",....  should get converted to [{"RECORD_TYPE":"HEADER",.......

Try this -
Assuming you have the data in the variable called df, first you get all columns that start with RECORDS_. Since you have a dynamic schema for those columns, use schema_of_json to get the dynamic schema which then you can use it to convert the string JSON to JSON object.
cols = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('RECORDS_')]

for col in cols:
    data = df.filter(F.col(col).isNotNull()).select(col).head()
    if data is not None:
        schema = F.schema_of_json(data[0])
        df = df.withColumn(col, F.from_json(F.col(col), schema))

df.write.json('s3a://...')

